# Finding maximum values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the simplest way to find the largest value of a field when there are 2 or more results?

I've been playing with the W3Schools site using the orders table.  I've tried to display all the rows with the largest employee number (9).  Here is the link - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_avg

I can only figure out how to get it to print out one row.  How can I get it to print all of the results?

I tried the following:

```
select max(EmployeeID)
from orders;
```

and just get the result of 9.  I'm having trouble getting my head around this.

Comment: `max(EmployeeID)` returns the greatest value of `EmployeeID` in the table.  There can only be one maximum number, so 9 is the whole result of that query.  Just as there can be only one result for average, as in the sample you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAX() is an aggregate function, and all aggregate functions return only one row.

To get all the rows of the order table which belong to the employee with the highest id use a sub-query this

```
select *
from orders
where EmployeeID  = (select max(EmployeeID) from orders);
```